# Google Maps API - Is there a way to reverse a listener on the next click?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, listener

I have a function which allows me to click on a marker and it provides me with an info box and another marker.

```
function addMarker(props){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:props.coords,
                    map: map,
                    icon:props.iconImage
                });

                if(props.content){
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content:props.content
                    });

                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        addMarker({
                        coords:{lat: 59.896874,lng: -5.125914},
                        iconImage:'pointer12s.png',
                        content:'<h1>destination</h1>'                
                        }); 
                    });
                  
                }

            }
```

Is there a way to then remove these on the next click?

I have tried putting in variations of:

```
.removeEventListener
```

But i am unsure whether to put it into the same function or use a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to keep a reference to the marker that was added.  If it hasn't been added, create the marker, if it already exists, hide it (call `setMap(null)`) then set it to null. Close the `InfoWindow` when you remove the marker.

```
  var addedMarker;
  function addMarker(props) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: props.coords,
      map: map,
      icon: props.iconImage
    });

    if (props.content) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
      });
      marker.infowindow = infoWindow;
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        if (!addedMarker || !addedMarker.setMap) {
        addedMarker = addMarker({
          coords: {
            lat: 59.896874,
            lng: -5.125914
          },
          // iconImage: 'pointer12s.png',
          content: '<h1>destination</h1>'
        });
        } else {
          this.infowindow.close();
          addedMarker.setMap(null);
          addedMarker = null;
        }
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3d4rLfew/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
(function(exports) {
  "use strict";
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {
      lat: 59.896874,
      lng: -5.125914
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatLng
    });
    addMarker({
      coords: {
        lat: 59.8,
        lng: -5.0
      },
      content: "content"
    });
  }
  var addedMarker;
  function addMarker(props) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: props.coords,
      map: map,
      icon: props.iconImage
    });

    if (props.content) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
      });
      marker.infowindow = infoWindow;
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        if (!addedMarker || !addedMarker.setMap) {
        addedMarker = addMarker({
          coords: {
            lat: 59.896874,
            lng: -5.125914
          },
          // iconImage: 'pointer12s.png',
          content: '<h1>destination</h1>'
        });
        } else {
          this.infowindow.close();
          addedMarker.setMap(null);
          addedMarker = null;
        }
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }
  exports.initMap = initMap;
})((this.window = this.window || {}));
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Markers</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```